# Lorenz Gauge and Pauli-Lubanski vector

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, gauge-theory

I am trying to understand the origin of the gauge condition $\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}=0$. For the polarization 4-vector, $\epsilon_{\mu}$, the equivalent statement would be $k^{\mu} \epsilon_{\mu}=0$, which is sometimes referred as the transversality condition.

From Poincare group we know that spin pseudo-vector is defined as:
$$W_{\mu}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\mu \nu \lambda \rho}J^{\nu \lambda}P^{\rho}$$
and the corresponding Casimir operator have the eigenvalues $W^2=-m^2 s (s+1)$. From the definition above we have the transversality condition: $W_{\mu} P^{\mu}=0$.

These two transversality conditions look quite similar. Are they in fact related ?  put it another way, can $W_{\mu}$ be related $\epsilon_{\mu}$ ?